# Making Multipart Features to Unique features

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I have a layer with two lines crossing over each other. I create intersection point over them and then create a buffer for a specified distance and then using difference tool, I delete the buffer area.

The resultant of the above process is four individual lines. Although the lines are four, the features are only two since they have been just separated by the above process.

What is the way to make the feature of each one unique so that I get a total distinct feature of four?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `Vector-> Geometry Tools -> Multipart To Single Parts`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Multipart Split Plugin](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/splitmultipart/), available in the QGIS oficial repository to transform selected multipart features into Single parts during editing.

Comment: +1, this is pretty cool! ..now users do not have to export to a new layer even for splitting a couple of multi-part features..